# Confusing uninitialized value and conditional jump indications in valgrind output

Tags: c++, initialization, valgrind

Running an SDL Linux multimedia application through valgrind, one of the errors that pops up often is a conditional jump based on an uninitialized value, yet I can't pinpoint the problem in the code. It looks like a false positive, but I'm confused by valgrind's output.

My problem is two-fold: 1) I don't see a conditional jump on the line valgrind says it happened, and 2) I don't see a problematic allocation on the line where it says the uninitialized value originates.

Here's an example of this error from running `valgrind --track-origins=yes`:

```
126 ==10430== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
127 ==10430==    at 0x60F9135: getenv (getenv.c:84)
128 ==10430==    by 0x6161485: tzset_internal (tzset.c:405)
129 ==10430==    by 0x6161648: __tz_convert (tzset.c:624)
130 ==10430==    by 0x406EC5: CLog::IIOCP_LogMessage(char const*, ...) (Log.cpp:80)
131 ==10430==    by 0x41453A: ConnectionThread::Connect() (ConnectionThread.cpp:224)
132 ==10430==    by 0x4149C5: ConnectionThread::DoRun() (ConnectionThread.cpp:318)
133 ==10430==    by 0x41499F: ConnectionThread::IOClientThread(void*) (ConnectionThread.cpp:313)
134 ==10430==    by 0x50D1B4F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:304)
135 ==10430==    by 0x619F7BC: clone (clone.S:112)
136 ==10430==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
137 ==10430==    at 0x4057D0: Video::DrawGraphic() (video.cpp:49)
```

This is the DrawGraphics method:

```
void Video::DrawGraphic(void)
{
    if (exp_timer)
    {   
        if (MainSur != NULL)
        {   
            SurBlit();
            exp_timer = false;
        }   
        else
        {   
            printf("\nError in DrawGraphic: MainSur is NULL.\n");
        }   
        FPS++;
        if (SDL_GetTicks() - TicksReadPipe >= 1000)
        {   
            ScrStrategy.OnReadPackets(connThread.GetPackets());
            TicksReadPipe = SDL_GetTicks();
        }   
    }   
    if (SDL_GetTicks() - CurrentTicks >= 1000)
    {   
        CurrentTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
        FPS = 0;   
    }   
}
```

All the variables are members of the `Video` class and were allocated on construction. I don't see any stack allocations here.

And this is the `getenv` function (with a collapsed if-branch we've not entered). My version of glibc is [2.13-38+deb7u6_all.deb](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/eglibc-source/download), function is in `usr/src/glibc/eglibc-2.13/stdlib/getenv.c`:

```
33 char *
34 getenv (name)
35      const char *name;
36 {
37   size_t len = strlen (name);
38   char **ep;
39   uint16_t name_start;
40 
41   if (__environ == NULL || name[0] == '\0')
42     return NULL;
43 
44   if (name[1] == '\0')
45 +-- 25 lines: {-------------------------------------------------------------
70   else
71     {
72 #if _STRING_ARCH_unaligned
73       name_start = *(const uint16_t *) name;
74 #else
75       name_start = (((const unsigned char *) name)[0]
76             | (((const unsigned char *) name)[1] << 8));
77 #endif
78       len -= 2;
79       name += 2;
80 
81       for (ep = __environ; *ep != NULL; ++ep)
82     {
83 #if _STRING_ARCH_unaligned
84       uint16_t ep_start = *(uint16_t *) *ep;
85 #else
86       uint16_t ep_start = (((unsigned char *) *ep)[0]
87                    | (((unsigned char *) *ep)[1] << 8));
88 #endif
89 
90       if (name_start == ep_start && !strncmp (*ep + 2, name, len)
91           && (*ep)[len + 2] == '=')
92         return &(*ep)[len + 3];
93     }
94     }
95     
96   return NULL;
97 }
```

I don't see a conditional jump on line 84.

`getenv` is indeed called from `tzset_internal`, at `tzset.c:405`, and `tzset_internal` itself is called from `__tz_convert` at `tzset.c:624`, so I believe the source I'm looking at matches the debug symbols valgrind uses.

Am I missing something, or if not, why is valgrind pointing me to these source lines/chunks?

Comment: is your `Video` object allocated/constructed on the stack?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's also a non-static global.

Comment: so presumably valgrind is complaining about one of the member variables of the Video object... check those out...

Comment: I'm still debugging and so far everything I've checked seems initialized. But if your presumption is true, and taking into account that DrawGraphics is not called in the constructor, wouldn't valgrind have to point to where the object was actually allocated, not to DrawGraphics' code block?

Comment: it's a virtual machine and it's simply tracking low-level memory access.  it doesn't presume where you should be doing initialization or allocation.  all it knows is 'at this point, you used a chunk of memory that was never initialized.'

Comment: As I understand the manual for `track-origins`, Memcheck _does_ claim the uninitialized value was allocated in DrawGraphics. _For uninitialised values originating from a stack allocation, Memcheck can tell you which function allocated the value, but no more than that -- typically it shows you the source location of the opening brace of the function._

Comment: mcmlxxxvi, have you found the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm currently rewriting the app and have not run valgrind on it recently, but will most likely get back to this issue when I'm done.

Comment: Unfortunately yet again, I've moved to another company and don't have access to the source code that produced the condition. There's a chance  I'll bump into the same issue at some later point and get back to this question, but it's extremely slim.